# Bluetooth earphones not working with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth

I have some Bluetooth 5.0 earphones. They work fine with my android phone, but when I connect them to my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop (HP Spectre x360) they connect for a second or two, but then the sound kinda freezes and makes a weird noise like something has crashed.

Just hoping that someone had an idea about what could be tried if anything.

---

The output of: `systemctl | grep -i blue` is:

```
sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:14.0-usb1-1\x2d7-1\x2d7:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device                                                                                    loaded active     plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0                                                                 
  sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device                                                                                                                         loaded active     plugged   /sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0                                                                                                
  bluetooth.service                                                                                                                                                   loaded active     running   Bluetooth service                                                                                                                    
  bluetooth.target                                                                                                                                                    loaded active     active    Bluetooth
```

The output of: `dmesg | grep -i blue` is:

```
[   15.559912] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   15.559928] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.559931] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.559933] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.559939] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   15.592313] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[   15.596950] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[   15.773296] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[   15.790315] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[   17.687442] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   17.687444] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   17.687448] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   49.401967] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   49.401973] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   49.401978] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[23668.832623] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[23668.832631] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[23669.117611] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[23669.134650] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[27326.736738] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[27326.736863] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[27326.996746] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[27327.013792] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[35858.296613] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[35858.296623] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[35858.532597] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[35858.549611] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[38574.248283] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[38574.248388] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[38574.472263] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[38574.489337] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[49428.524736] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[49428.524741] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[49428.772715] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[49428.789740] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[49457.069618] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[49457.069841] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[49457.359639] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[49457.376683] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[64426.066133] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[64426.066147] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[64426.363108] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[64426.380127] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[76145.491667] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[76145.491906] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[76145.743626] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[76145.760633] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[76274.188201] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[76274.188205] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[76274.432187] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[76274.449202] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[78184.128673] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[78184.128810] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[78184.340540] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[78184.357539] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[82111.923062] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[82111.923067] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[82112.120036] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[82112.137037] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[90047.485285] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[90047.485508] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[90047.784268] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[90047.801304] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[90230.749441] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e00
[90230.749446] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[90230.974392] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[90230.991415] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
```

The output of: `lspci` is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:13.0 Non-VGA unclassified device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 61)
```

Comment: Please add the output of `systemctl | grep -i blue`, `dmesg | grep -i blue` and `lspci`

Comment: Which bluetooth profile are you using `HSP` or `A2DP Sink`?

Comment: I don't know what `HSP` or `A2DP Sink` are but I have added the outputs requested so hopefully that will provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

I had exact same issue as you described on Ubuntu 20.04. Try this out:

Edit Bluetooth configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

Replace:

```
#ControllerMode = dual
```

with:

```
ControllerMode = bredr
```

Restart Bluetooth:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Try to connect your headset again.

Comment: Thank you - I tried this, but the same thing happened unfortunately. The sound crashes and then one of the earphones says "disconnected" and the other says "power on" (even though the power was already on).